# Saving and loading game data in my android app

Tags: java, android, json, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm working on a sports simulation app where the user can pick their team and control a roster of players, sim through their schedule, etc. The whole process is broken up into a League object that has a list of Conference objects that has a list of Team objects that has a list of Player objects and so on. Right now there is no way for the user to save their game, close out of the app, start the app back up, and load their game to where they were before. I'm trying to think of the best way to handle saving/loading all of the data that's contained in my objects.

Would it be overkill to use android's sqlite library to read from a database and instantiate all of the objects when the user loads their game? Or would I want to convert all of my objects to JSON when the user saves and then read those in and instantiate the objects when the user loads? I'm unsure what the best practice would be for this type of situation in android.

Comment: Both would work. If you're a beginner, implement both, compare them, and learn from it.

Comment: @CL. I'm not as much of a beginner in programming in general, but definitely am when it comes to using databases. I think I am going to implement both and see what works the best. Is it typical for games or apps that use a lot of objects to do what I described? Basically doing all of their querying/reading at the beginning to load data into a bunch of objects and then later do a bunch of querying/writing to save that data for the next time the user plays/uses the app?

Comment: This is called serialization. There are many programs that write/read all their data at once, but many other programs operate directly on the database. What to do depends on whether your program actually needs to do all its processing in memory.